# How to create xPath for java code in PMD rules in Eclipse

Tags: pmd

I want to create an xPath to add PMD rule to avoid the below code:

```
String variable = null;
variable.equals("String");
```

which throws a `null pointer exception`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not really understand the question. Could you show some more of the context? Maybe describe why you want to use xpath? To avoid a null pointer error?? Describe what PMD is, maybe? Is this a programming question, even? Is this of value to others, or will a quick look in the PMD documentation reveal the answer?

Comment: sorry I mean how to create an xpath expression to add a customized pmd rule to identify the java code - a.equals("literal"); in the below code:
public class TestPMDRules {

 public void method(String a) {
  
  if (a.equals("literal")) {  //here I need xpath expression to identify
   System.out.println("May get NullPointerException");
   }
  }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  TestPMDRules tst = new TestPMDRules();
  String a = null;
  tst.method(a);
 }

} I hope now you understand my query

Comment: That rule already exists in PMD, and if you check the documentation, it's implemented in XPath: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.3.3/pmd-java/rules/java/design.html#PositionLiteralsFirstInComparisons